# Context API setState from Children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to Context API, while playing around with it, I have trouble access and setting the state from the child (Movie.js).

Run-time error

> TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

How to resolve this?

**MovieContext.js - parent**

```
import React, { useState, createContext, Children } from "react";

export const MovieContext = createContext();

export const MovieProvider = (props) => {
  const [movies, setMovie] = useState({
    name: "Happy Potter",
    releaseDate: "22 June 2015",
    price: 20,
    id: 23232,
  });

  return <MovieContext.Provider>{props.children}</MovieContext.Provider>;
};
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Movie from "./Movie";
import { MovieContext, MovieProvider } from "./MovieContext";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <MovieProvider>
          <Movie />
        </MovieProvider>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Movie.js - child**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { MovieContext } from "./MovieContext";

const Movie = () => {
    const [movies, setMovie] = useContext(MovieContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{movies.name}</h3>
      <h2>{movies.releaseDate}</h2>
      <h2>{movies.price}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movie;
```

Comment: The error message on run-time is "TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))"

Comment: You simply forgot to pass value to your provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[movies, setMovie] needs to be passed as props in MovieContext.Provider.

```
 return (
    <MovieContext.Provider value={[movies, setMovie]}>
      {props.children}
    </MovieContext.Provider>
  );
```

**Note: props is an array not an object [movies, setMovie]**

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass movies state in content Provider in order to consume later on.

```
return <MovieContext.Provider 
           value={{
                 movies,
                 setMovies
           }}>
              {props.children}
       </MovieContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: Also dont forget to change useContext brackets to curly brackets.